# What does the semi-colon at the beginning of this loop mean?

Tags: java, android

I was reading an open source code when I came across this semi-colon. I initially thought it was an error but it wasn't.

whats the function of the semicolon right after the open brackets of the for-loop below?

```
       if (nCount > 0){
            for(; nCount > 0; nCount--){
                if (mBitmaplist[nCount - 1] != null){
                    mBitmaplist[nCount - 1].recycle();
                    mBitmaplist[nCount - 1] = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `for(;;)` is perfectly valid Java.  It's effectively the same as `while(true)`.

Comment: This is explained in the Oracle Java Tutorial ... and every half-decent Java textbook.

Comment: The `for` syntax comes from C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that means there is no statement for initializer part of for loop

similarly if you want to skip the increment portion of for loop it would look like

```
for( ; nCount > 0; ){
  // some code
}

// which is like while loop
```

[From JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14) this is the format of for loop

```
BasicForStatement:
    for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) Statement
```

you can see that all 3 are optional

Answer (score 2):

The statement `for (PART1; PART2; PART3) { BODY }` works something like this:

```
PART1;

<<TOP OF LOOP>>
if PART2 is false then go to <<END OF LOOP>>;
do the BODY;
PART3;
go to <<TOP OF LOOP>>;

<<END OF LOOP>>
```

If you say `for (; PART2; PART3)` that just means `PART1` does nothing.  (Same thing for `PART3`.  If you leave out `PART2`, then nothing is tested, and the `go to <<END OF LOOP>>` never happens.  So the only way to get to the end of the loop is with a `break` or `return` or something.)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this example helps you understand better:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0; // you normally put this before the first semicolon in next line
    for (;;) {
        if (i > 5) {
            break; // this "if" normally goes between the 2 semicolons
        }
        System.out.println("printing:" + i);
        i++; // this is what you put after the second semi-colon
    }
}
```

Have fun with Java and keep coding on!